# Defining Copy Constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, copy-constructor

This is my class:

```
class Cat {
    static int lives = 9;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Cat(String s, int i) {
        name = s;
        age = i;
    }
    public Cat(Cat c) {
       // Failed attempt to define Copy Constructor
        return new Cat(c.name,c.age);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (name + ", " + age);
    }
}
```

I wanted to define the copy constructor so that I could instantiate a new object of Cat from an existing one. Like this:

```
Cat Garfield = new Cat("Garfield",10);
Cat Tom = new Cat(Garfield);
```

When I try it out, it gives me compilation error with the copy constructor definition. Please help me understand what's wrong. Yes, the constructor can't have return types and yet we are returning a reference to Cat here.

Comment: I know the copy constructor definition is flawed but how do I implement it correctly?

Answer (score 7):

Don't do

```
return new Cat(c. ...
```

but

```
this(c.name, ...)
```

Constructors don't return objects via return!

Comment: I know. But, `this` is a pointer to the invoking instance of the class, right? So, how can we use `this` in this way?

Comment: `this` is a reference to the current object, java do not have pointer like C/C++. If you don't want to call the constructor you can do `this.name = c.name`, ...

Answer (score 3):

A constructor does not return anything. In a constructor, you are given the "skeleton" of your new object (the reference `this`), and you initialize it properly as you see fit.

So the first step is to call the proper constructor using that reference, to initialize basic things:

```
this( c.name, c.age );
```

And then, since this is a copy constructor, and supposedly you want to get a complete copy of the original `Cat`, you should proceed to initialize the rest of the fields if you have any.

For example, if you had a field `int remainingLives` which in your normal constructor was initialized to `lives`, but the other `Cat` already lost three lives, then you would have to follow the call to the constructor by

```
remainingLives = c.remainingLives;
```

Otherwise it would not be a true copy.

Comment: You bloody beauty. I like this new brought up. Thanks buddy. :)

Comment: @Southee I'm glad you like it. So will you consider marking the answer as "accepted"? This is the way to say "Thanks, it is the answer I was looking for" in StackOverflow. Consider doing the same for answers on your previous questions, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor should ideally look like

```
public Cat(Cat c) {
  name = c.name;
  age = c.age; 
 }
```

(assuming you are using this constructor to create an object of class'Cat' using using an existing object of 'Cat')